# performance of using getter in javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there a performance difference between these 2 calls?

```
get getId() {        
  delete this.getId;
  return (this.getId = document.getElementById('tempId'));    
}

get getId() {    
  return document.getElementById('tempId');
}
```

Usage is

```
if (this.getId) {
  this.getId.appendChild(<something>);
} else {
  var self = this;
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    self.getId.appendChild(<something>);
  });
}
```

Comment: jsperf and do the benckmark yourself.

Comment: just try Chrome Dev tools using F12 or Firebug